# Consolidating two columns with duplicates into two columns without the duplicates

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I am trying to extract some data from a spreadsheet i have.  there are two columns that have duplicate data and am trying to take the duplication out with a formula.  here is what i have and what I am trying to do.

```
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3D152 Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3D152 Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3D152 Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3D152 Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3D152 Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3D153 Edit Code 03
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3D153 Edit Code 03
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3D153 Edit Code 03
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3D153 Edit Code 03
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3D153 Edit Code 03
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
```

and trying to get it to do this with formulas in another table.

```
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3D152 Edit Code 02
A1C Tracy, Timothy J    Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3D153 Edit Code 03
Amn Decker, Jack H      Z3DX5X Edit Code 02
```

I have done this to try and sort it.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$3:B$47,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(Y2:Y$2,B$3:B$47),0)),"")
```

but will only return 1 name not both to match the to the other column

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do this through formula?

Comment: Apologize that it did not format to the two columns that i wanted

Comment: the columns will not change but the data in them will,

Comment: And what version of Excel have you got?

Comment: it is excel 2016, and the data tab will not work because of the other data that is in the spreadsheet.  that is why i am looking for a formula that will do the above,so then i can put the other data in there and will help with other parts of the workbook that will reference the consolidated data

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, there's a solution

1. Select all cells of the tableG
2. Open the **Data tab**

[image: cells selected and Data tab is open]

3. Select the **"remove duplicates"** button

[image: remove duplicates button]

4. Make sure all columns are selected in the modal box as seen below and hit OK

[image: modal box]

5. Voila

[image: Yay!! It worked]